# A click on the caret of a segmented button doesn't trigger the click event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am unable to capture the click event when I click the caret of a segmented button in Bootstrap 3. I am pretty sure that no event is triggered but would really like to understand why. This is driving me crazy. I have tested this on Firefox and Chrome and didn't work. I haven't tested it with earlier versions of Bootstrap.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/40frLqyg/1/

HTML

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn ov-grp-div">
            <button tabindex="-1" class="ovtarget-btn btn btn-default" type="button">
                Action
            </button>
            <button tabindex="-1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="ov"><a href="#"> Action-1</a></li>
                <li class="ov"><a href="#"> Action-2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Category">

    </div>
</div>

<div id="clickLogger">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
    $("#clickLogger").append("Clicked<BR>");
});
```

Thanks

Comment: `$(document).on("click", ".caret", function(event) {`. Check [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/40frLqyg/2/)

Comment: Actually, `$(document).on("click", ".caret", function(event)` just works when you click exactly on the caret image. The dropbown can appear without triggering the event if you click beside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the trigger to the dropdown rather than the caret:

```
 $(document).on("click", ".dropdown-toggle", function(event) {
    $("#clickLogger").append("Clicked<BR>");
});
```

If on the caret, the mouse has to be right on top to trigger it, but the mouse could be just to the side.Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/40frLqyg/8/

Comment: Great answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$(document).on("click",`.caret` ,function(event) {
    $("#clickLogger").append("Clicked<BR>");
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/40frLqyg/4/)

or

```
$(document).on({
    click: function (event) {
        $("#clickLogger").append("Clicked<BR>");
    }
}, `.caret`);
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/40frLqyg/6/)

Comment: @Alexander it works if you click on the `triangle shape`(`.caret`).

Comment: You can change `.caret` to `.btn.dropdown-toggle` to support more space.

Comment: @Alexander Does it fix your problem?